# How can i make an angular async validator timeout

Tags: html, angular

Firstly i have this async validator for angular for password validation and I'm trying to make a delay for the message in html but it doesnt seem to work, how do i need to call it to work.I checked via console.log(control) in the function and it returns the expected result but it still appears instantly on how i called it in HTML code.

I will put sample code here.
Here i make the form with the validators.

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder)
  {
    this.form = fb.group({
      password: ['', Validators.required,this.asyncValidator],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required,this.asyncValidator]
    })
  }
```

Here is the validation function.

```
asyncValidator(control:FormControl):any{
    return new Promise(
      (resolve) =>{
        setTimeout(() => {
          if((control.password).length < 6 && (control.password).length > 1)
              console.log("true");
          console.log("false");
          resolve(null);
        },2000);
      }
    );
 }
```

Here is the HTML code that i use in the page to see the delayed message(that doesn't work).

```
<div class="alert alert-danger"
  *ngIf="asyncValidator(this.form.controls.password)">Password too short</div>
```

How do i need to use the async validator so my message in HTML appears with a 2 secs delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood what async validators do and how they're used and written. Hence, there are a lot of issues with your implementation. Here's how you can fix them.

**1. Get rid of the code in your `constructor` and move it to `ngOnInit`:**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    password: ['', [Validators.required], [this.asyncValidator.bind(this)]],
    confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required], [this.asyncValidator.bind(this)]]
  });
}
```

**Rationale:** `constructor`s are supposed to be skinny [**according to**](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/) Misko Hevery

> Experienced developers agree that components should be cheap and safe to construct.

And, the [**`async`**](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validator-functions) validators, are passed as the third argument to a [**`FormControl`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl)

Also, since the `async` validators are functions that are going to be called by Angular and not by us, we need to set the context of `this` explicitly by calling `bind(this)` on the async validator function.

**2. Now, the promise returned by the `asyncValidator`, should resolve to `null` in case of no error and an error object in case of an error:**

```
asyncValidator(control: FormControl): any {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if ((control.value).length < 6 && (control.value).length > 1)
          resolve(null);
        else
          resolve({
            shortPassword: true
          });
      }, 2000);
    }
  );
}
```

**3. Create a function that is going to return a boolean based on whether a `FormControl` is touched and has an error that you're returning from your `asyncValidator` function:**

```
getFormControlError(controlName) {
  const control = this.form.get(controlName);
  return control.touched && control.errors && control.errors.shortPassword;
}
```

**Rationale:** This is something that we'll be using in our template.

**4. Update your template to show the error only if the input field is touched and has that error:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  Password: <input type="text" formControlName="password">
  <div class="alert alert-danger"
  *ngIf="getFormControlError('password')">Password too short</div>

  <br><br>

  Confirm Password: <input type="text" formControlName="confirmPassword"> 
  <div class="alert alert-danger"
  *ngIf="getFormControlError('confirmPassword')">Password too short</div>
  <br> 
  <br>
</form>
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-async-validators?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Thank you for your complex answer, as i said this was a sample code(not my complete code) but as you said i didn't understand that clearly how async validators work and are written, i can see my mistakes now and everything is more clear!